# Rounded corners for 2d rectangle with Python

Tags: python

in my addon I have a 2d shape (polyline) for which I want to add rounded corners (step-wise, like the bevel does, when added edges for the bevel).

[image]

This means I want to decide that I add for example 2, 3, or any number of points like this:

[image]

And then connect these with my polyline.

Does anybody no the algorithmn for this?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120114/square-spiral-path/120191#120191)

Comment: Well, a bit, but I have 2d points that I draw with opengl / gpu and I just need to add more points to create a round corner, same functionality that bevel has just for 2d.

Comment: Basic trig, put a circle, radius r,  in the corner.  You have a corner pt, (x, y) centre of circle will be (x -r , y - r)  Arc one quadrant. Same principle as link above.

Comment: ok, understood, the circle is kinda the perfect match. but how to find the points (e.g. 2, 3, 4...) on this circle?