# How to hide occluded faces？

Tags: scripting

[image]

Pure gpu drawing, no entity

Is there a way to hide the occluded face?

```py
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

coords = (
    (-1, -1, -1), (+1, -1, -1),
    (-1, +1, -1), (+1, +1, -1),
    (-1, -1, +1), (+1, -1, +1),
    (-1, +1, +1), (+1, +1, +1))

indices = (
    (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3),
    (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7),
    (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=indices)


def draw():
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 1))
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

---

The above is a simple example,let me add it with a model

### Current display

[image]

### Desired effect

[image]

Certain effects can be achieved through the calculation of normals

```py
def get_front_faces(_bm, _rgn, _rv3d, _matrix):
    if not _rv3d:
        raise Exception('get_front_idx: rv3d error')
    if not _rgn:
        raise Exception('get_front_idx: rgn error')

    eye = Vector(_rv3d.view_matrix[2][:3])
    eye.length = _rv3d.view_distance
    eye_location = _rv3d.view_location + eye

    faces = []

    rv = None
    is_perspective = _rv3d.is_perspective
    if not is_perspective:
        co = location_3d_to_region_2d(_rgn, _rv3d, eye_location)
        rv = region_2d_to_vector_3d(_rgn, _rv3d, co) * -1
        rv.normalize()

    for bmf in [bmf for bmf in _bm.faces if bmf.is_valid]:
        if is_perspective:
            center = _matrix @ bmf.calc_center_median()
            rv = eye_location - center
            rv.normalize()
        dot_value = bmf.normal.dot(rv)  
        if dot_value < 0:
            continue
        else:
            faces.append(bmf)
    return faces
```

But it won’t work for complex faces
[image]

As you can see, the inner surface should be occluded, I don’t want to show it

Comment: Do you mean the occluded vert, (_ie_ the one that appears to be nearest the origin in image above)?  If we consider faces here, would say it is the vert joined to all back faces. _ie_ faces whose normals face primarily away from view.

Comment: Could add the face indices calc all the normals, however  would do same as here   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230545/rounded-corners-for-2d-rectangle  and use the mesh API provides.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the reply, I added the description

Comment: Hmmm akin to  a freestyle render on screen.  GPU is not really my thing so spit-balling here: could project from view https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160388/15543 (via cam, use view instead) then texture faces with a gpu buffer image of the bg.  Or work out some routine to process the flattened mesh finding crossing points.